# On compact expressions for determinants of matrices having polynomial entries with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, derivatives, binomial-coefficients, determinant

Let $m,n,r$ be positive integers with $r+1\le m\le n$ .  Let $t$ be a variable and $A(t)=[a_{ij}(t)] $ be a $r\times r$ matrix with entries being polynomials in the variable $t$ namely $a_{ij}(t)=\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{m-i}{k} \binom {n-j}{k+i-j}t^k$ , where by convention $\binom {a}{b}=0$ if $a<b$. Now consider the polynomial $h(t)=\det A(t)$.

Are there nice compact expressions for the following two quantities: $h(1)$ and $h'(1)$ ? At least can we get an expression when $m=n$ and $r=2$ ?

Comment: Computing $h\left(1\right)$ means removing the $t^k$ factor from the formula for $a_{ij}(t)$. This turns the formula into something you can simplify using Vandermonde convolution to a single binomial coefficient. The resulting determinant should be in [Krattenthaler](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004) or close. I don't know about $h'(1)$ off the bat.

Comment: @darij grinberg: for Vandermonde type identity you need to sum over things like $\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{r-k}$ as your sum varies over $k$ so that $k+(r-k)$ doesn't depend on the index we're summing over ... such a situation does not seem to happen for my expression ...

Comment: $\sum_k \dbinom{m-i}{k} \dbinom{n-j}{k+i-j} = \sum_k \dbinom{m-i}{k} \dbinom{n-j}{\left(n-j\right) - \left(k+i-j\right)}$ $= \sum_k \dbinom{m-i}{k} \dbinom{n-j}{n-i-k} = \dbinom{\left(m-i\right)+\left(n-j\right)}{n-i}$ by Vandermonde.